# Array Push Function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

problem is simple i am trying to push values in array but it's creating every time new one instead to add i tried many ways to do the same thing you can check code here what actually i am doing

```
$(function(){
        // Append Theme Pages
 let counter = 2;    
 $(".js-append-pages").on("click", function(){
        $(".js-pages-append-area").append(
            `<div class="input-field col xs12 s6">
                    <input name="page_${counter}" id="page_${counter}" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="page_${counter}">Page Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="file-field input-field col xs12 s6">
                    <div class="btn">
                        <span>Image</span>
                        <input type="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input name="page_${counter}_img" class="file-path validate" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>`);

                let inputArr = ["page_1"];

            inputArr.push(`page_${counter}`);
            console.log(inputArr);

                counter++;
 });

})
```

Comment: every time you click, you do `let inputArr = ["page_1"];` therefore you re-initialise the inputArr variable on each click. If you don't want to do that, don't put that code inside the click handler

Comment: without putting inside the click handler how i can do the some task

Comment: actually i got your point you are right need to just put this - let inputArr = ["page_1"]; outside of the code thanx to give me your precious time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function (){

    let counter = 1;
    let inputArr = ["page_1"];

    $(".js-append-pages").on("click", function ()
    {
        $(".js-pages-append-area").append(
            `<div class="input-field col xs12 s6">
                <input name="page_${counter}" id="page_${counter}" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="page_${counter}">Page Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="file-field input-field col xs12 s6">
                <div class="btn">
                    <span>Image</span>
                    <input type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input name="page_${counter}_img" class="file-path validate" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>`);

        inputArr.push(`page_${++counter}`);
        console.log(inputArr);

    });
});
```

This should be a better way to implement it.

Comment: thanx but we already discussed this issue above and u are right too